# Delete CHOOSEN special character function

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, tkinter

please help cause Im loosing my mind. I can find similar problems but none of them is that specific.

-Im trying to create a simple compilator in Tkinter, with the function to delete a choosen special character.
-I got the buttons for each character (dot, colon, etc.), and I want to create a function that would take a special character as an argument, then delete it from the ScrolledText field. Here is my best try:

```
import re

content = 'Test. test . .test'
special = '.'

def delchar(char):
    adjustedchar = str("'[" + char + "]'")
    p = re.compile(adjustedchar)
    newcontent = p.sub('', content)
    print(newcontent)

delchar(special)
```

output (nothing has changed)>>> 'Test. test . .test'

What's going on here? How to make it work? Is there a better solution?
I know that I could create each function for each character (tried, and it's working), but that would create a 10 uneccesary functions. I want to keep it DRY. Also, my next function is gonna do the same thing, just using the user-input.

What doesn't work is that argument. If I would print eg. adjustedchar, I'd get:

'[.]'

It's a format that re.compile() should accept, right?

Comment: so you want to replace `.` with `'[.]'`? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Bryan, my intention was to delete dots in this particular case

Comment: Just use `re.sub("\.", "", content)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works the problem is that `.` (a dot) is a special character.
Change your code to:

```
import re

content = 'Test. test . .test'
special = '\.'

def delchar(char):
    adjustedchar = str("'[" + char + "]'")
    p = re.compile(char)
    newcontent = p.sub('', content)
    print(newcontent)

delchar(special)
```

You can also check by making `special = 't'`. In your function you can do checks for the special characters.

Comment: Hi Mick, no problem. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re.compile with the pattern you want to match, not with the replace-content:

```
import re

content = 'Test. test . .test'
special = '.'

def delchar(char):
    adjustedchar = str("'[" + char + "]'")
    p = re.compile("["+char+"]")     # replace the dots, not '.'
    newcontent = p.sub(adjustedchar, content) # with adjustedchar,change to '' if you like
    print(newcontent)

delchar(special)
```

Your `content` does not contain `'.'` so it does not replace. If you change the pattern to `"[.]"` you are looking for literal dots to be replaced - not dots flanked by `'`

Output:

```
Test'[.]' test '[.]' '[.]'test
```

You could as well just use string replace:  `Test. Test .  .test'.replace(".","'.'")`

Comment: Patrick, it works like charm, and if I want to delete dots completely, I can get rid of the adjustedchar. Genious! Thank you! And actually, I can also just remove ' from adjustedchar, like: str("[" + char + "]")